# TypeError: ReactHotAPI is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

Error description,

```
TypeError: ReactHotAPI is not a function
<anonymous>
 bundle.js:2632
<anonymous>
 bundle.js:2632
<anonymous>
 bundle.js:2632
__webpack_require__()
 bundle.js:556
hotCreateRequire/fn()
 bundle.js:87
<anonymous>
 bundle.js:2572
<anonymous>
 bundle.js:2572
<anonymous>
 bundle.js:2572
__webpack_require__()
 bundle.js:556
hotCreateRequire/fn()
 bundle.js:87
<anonymous>
 bundle.js:2347
__webpack_require__()
 bundle.js:556
hotCreateRequire/fn()
 bundle.js:87
<anonymous>
 bundle.js:1491
__webpack_require__()
 bundle.js:556
hotCreateRequire/fn()
 bundle.js:87
<anonymous>
 bundle.js:1411
<anonymous>
 bundle.js:1411
<anonymous>
 bundle.js:1411
__webpack_require__()
 bundle.js:556
hotCreateRequire/fn()
 bundle.js:87
<anonymous>
 bundle.js:698
<anonymous>
 bundle.js:698
<anonymous>
 bundle.js:698
__webpack_require__()
 bundle.js:556
hotCreateRequire/fn()
 bundle.js:87
<anonymous>
 bundle.js:595
<anonymous>
 bundle.js:595
__webpack_require__()
 bundle.js:556
hotCreateRequire/fn()
 bundle.js:87
<anonymous>
 bundle.js:586
__webpack_require__()
 bundle.js:556
<anonymous>
 bundle.js:579
<anonymous>
 bundle.js:1
 bundle.js:2632:318
```

My Webconfig,

```
module.exports = {
  ip: IP,
  port: PORT,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react-native': 'react-web',
      'ReactNativeART': 'react-art',
    },
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  entry: isProd? [
    config.paths.index
  ]: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://' + IP + ':' + PORT,
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    config.paths.index,
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'output'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
     new HasteResolverPlugin({
      platform: 'web',
      nodeModules: ['react-web']
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
      }
    }),
    isProd? new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      React: "react"
    }): new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new HtmlPlugin(),
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react&presets[]=stage-2&presets[]=stage-0'],
      include: [config.paths.src],
      exclude: '/node_module' 
      },
    { 
      test: /\.css$/, 
      loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
    },
    {
      test: /.*\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
      loader: 'file-loader'
    }],
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    }
  }
};
```

I tried so many ways to resolve this issue. Somewhere written exclude node modules it will works. Yes its works after exclude. I separately build GiftedMassanger for web but i'm not exclude any node modules. Now i GiftedMessanger integrate with my main application then i facing real cruel thing of webpack, if i exclude node modules then main app will work and gifted messenger will not. If i not exclude node modules then i got ReactHotAPI is not a function.  I want middle way to satisfy both thing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to exclude node_modules in your loaders - you excluded node_module - I think this should work.

```
loaders: [
      {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react&presets[]=stage-2&presets[]=stage-0'],
      include: [config.paths.src],
      exclude: '/node_modules/' 
      },
    { 
      test: /\.css$/, 
      loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
    },
    {
      test: /.*\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
      loader: 'file-loader'
    }]
```

Comment: I resolved that issue excluding node module same above mine setting but problem is i integrated some 3rd party library in my project that library depends on some of node modules so i need to included those node modules.